# Private Docker Registry Not Connectible to Shell & Web Management UI?

Tags: docker

#### Background:

To setup a **private docker registry server** at path *c:\dkrreg* on *localhost* on **Windows 10 (x64)** system, installed with **Docker for Windows**, have **successfully** tried following commands:

```
docker run --detach --publish 1005:5000 --name docker-registry --volume /c/dkrreg:/var/lib/registry registry:2
docker pull hello-world:latest
docker tag hello-world:latest localhost:1005/hello-world:latest
docker push localhost:1005/hello-world:latest
docker pull localhost:1005/hello-world:latest
```

Push and Pull from `localhost:1005/hello-world:latest` via command line succeeds too.

#### Issue:

If i use my IP address via `docker pull 192.168.43.239:1005/hello-world:latest` it gives following error in command shell:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.43.239:1005/v1/_ping: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

When using 3rd party Docker UI Manager via `docker run --detach portainer:latest` it also shows error to connect as:

```
2017/04/19 14:30:24 http: proxy error: dial tcp [::1]:1005: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Tried other stuff also. How can I connect my private registry server that is `localhost:1005` from LAN using any Docker Management UI tool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last find solution to this which was tricky

1. Generated CA private key and certificate as `ca-cert-mycompany.pem` and `ca-cert-key-companyname.pem`. And configured *docker-compose.yml* to save both files as ***:ro*** in these locations: `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`, `/etc/ssl/certs/`, `/etc/docker/certs.d/mysite.com`. But I also tried only copying certificate to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` was enough as docker will ignore duplicate CA certificates. This extra copying is because at many placed docker fellow recommended the same. I did not executed command: `update-ca-certificates` this time in registry container but was doing earlier as against what is suggested by many.
2. Defined in ***docker-compose.yml***: random number as `REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET`, and server's **chained certificate** (*CA certificate appended to end of it*) to `REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE` amd server's public key to `REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY`. Had disabled HTTP authentication. Especially used some naming for file names as found with other certificates in container folder as `mysite.com_server-chained-certificate.crt` instead of just `certificate.crt`.
3. ***V-Imp:*** pushed certificate to trusted root in windows using command `certutil.exe -addstore root .\Keys\ca-certificate.crt` followed with restarting ***Docker for Windows*** from taskbar icon and then creating container using `docker-compose up -d`. This is most important step without this nothing worked.

Now can perform `docker pull mysite.com:1005/my-repo:my-tag`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify to your Docker daemon that your registry is insecure: https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

Based on your OS/system, you need to change the configuration of the daemon to specify the registry address (format `IP:PORT`, use  `192.168.43.239:1005` rather than `localhost:1005`).

Once you have done that, you should be able to execute the following:

`docker pull 192.168.43.239:1005/hello-world:latest`

You should also be able to access it via Portainer using `192.168.43.239:1005` in the registry field.

If you want to access your registry using `localhost:1005` inside Portainer, you can try to run it inside the `host` network.

`docker run --detach --net host portainer:latest`

Comment: Using `docker run -d registry:2` able to run docker registry with output `...listening on [::]:5000 ...`. Now I don't find files `/etc/default/docker` or `/etc/sysconfig/docker` to change mode to unsecure from shell of docker container. Please advice on how to change listening IP address in docker registry container from dockerhub ?

Comment: Note that you should expose the registry port when running it `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 registry:2`. Also, have a look here to change your Docker daemon configuration when using Docker for Windows: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#custom-registries

Comment: Getting `Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.43.239:1005/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` error. How to go past, my certificates are chained with CA (CA is created by me only) and I've subjectAltName defined and copied ca.crt to `/etc/ssl/certs/ `, `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and other folders but failed

Comment: Are you using the `--insecure-registry` option? Also, you might want to have a look at this comment: https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1731#issuecomment-221411447

Comment: Yes tried could not function over IP as well as requirement is to operate with Security. I've also tried chaining certificates but not success. All certificates are shown as valid on other tools :(. Have tried all copying certificates to `/etc/docker/certs.d`, `/etc/docker/certs.d/<sitename>` and `/etc/docker/certs.d/<sitename:port>/` folders. URL provided does not say how problem was solved. Only nice thing here is that am not using HAproxy which actually is supposed to be simpler :(